# Looking for a word: Taking control or changing your environment

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard this word before but can't remember it. It is normally used to describe the stage of teenage development when the teenager starts to try and control or change their environment.

My brain keeps heading towards stewardship but I know it is not correct.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the emotion associated with this trait? Is the teenager doing this from the good of their heart, or are they doing it because they are angry or disappointed with the world?

Comment: I don't believe there is an emotion associated with the word. The word "agency" has now popped into my mind although it can be used in the same context. 

Agency - action or intervention producing a particular effect.
"canals carved by the agency of running water." 

I think the word I am looking for contains an "r". To use it in a sentence: "At this age, teenagers want to *word* of their life.